# How to compare the K-theory and singular cohomology of a classifying space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, topological-k-theory, classifying-spaces

In their foundational paper "Vector bundles and homogeneous spaces," Atiyah and Hirzebruch show, among many other things, that for $G$ a compact, connected Lie group, the K-theory of the classifying space $BG$, taken as an inverse limit of the K-theory of a family of compact approximations of $B_n G$, is isomorphic to the completion of the representation ring $R(G)$ at the augmentation ideal $I(G)$:

$$K^*(BG) := \varprojlim K^*(B_nG) \cong \varprojlim R(G)/I(G)^n =: \widehat R(G).$$

They make a point of noting that the Chern character, which is an isomorphism upon rationalizing on every compact approximation, extends to a map from $K^*(BG)$ to the completion of $H^*(BG;\mathbb Q)$ at the augmentation ideal $H^{\geq 1}(BG;\mathbb Q)$. They do **not** state that this becomes an **isomorphism** on tensoring with $\mathbb Q$, and I have seen it asserted that in fact it is not.

**Why not?**

Here is an argument that in fact it should be so for $G = S^1 = \mathrm{U}(1)$; perhaps someone can tell me where I've gone wrong.

The cohomology is $H^*(BS^1) = \mathbb{Z}[c]$, where $c \in H^2(BS^1)$ is the first Chern class. The completion is clearly $\hat H^*(BS^1;\mathbb Q) = \mathbb Q[[c]]$.

On the other hand, the representation ring is $R(S^1) = \mathbb Z[s,s^{-1}]$, where $s$ is the standard representation as scalar multiplication by the unit circle in $\mathbb C$. Atiyah–Hirzebruch argue the completion at the augmentation ideal $I(S^1) = (s-1) = (s-1,s^{-1}-1)$ is $\widehat R(S^1) = \mathbb Z[[s-1]]$. Tensoring with the rationals gives $\mathbb Q[[s-1]]$ [**edit: This is untrue; see Eric Wofsey's answer.**].

Now the Chern character takes $s \mapsto e^c$ in each approximation $H^*(B_n G)$, so it should take 
$$s-1 \longmapsto e^c -1 = c + c^2/2 + \cdots \in \hat H^*(BS^1).$$

It seems clear this is injective. As for surjectivity, as there is no constant term in $f(c) = e^c - 1$, it admits a composition-inverse $g$ in $\mathbb Q[[c]]$,
and then

$$g(s-1) \longmapsto g(f(c)) = c.$$

A similar argument would establish the same for $G = T$ a torus. **What goes wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that it is not true that the canonical map $i:\mathbb{Z}[[x]]\otimes\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ is an isomorphism.  Any power series of the image of $i$ must have only finitely many different denominators on its coefficients, since an element of $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ is a sum involving only finitely many elements of $\mathbb{Q}$.  So for instance, the power series $\sum x^n/n!$ is not in the image of $i$.

This means that your argument breaks down, and actually the completion of $H^*(BS^1;\mathbb{Q})$ is much larger than the image of $\widehat{R}(S^1)\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ under the Chern character (specifically, your argument shows that the Chern character extends to an isomorphism $\mathbb{Q}[[s-1]]\to \mathbb{Q}[[c]]$, and the image of the Chern character is just the image of $\mathbb{Z}[[s-1]]\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ under this isomorphism).

Comment: Ah! So the target should be, at smallest, the completion of $H^*(BG;\mathbb Q)$ and not simply tensoring with $\mathbb Q$. (I see now that this in fact is what Atiyah–Hirzebruch use as target; I'd naively missed the distinction. Now I have to edit the question.) But this is then much bigger and harder to map onto. Is the point then just that this will tank any hope of surjectivity without our extending the representation ring similarly?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's right.