# K-theory of a classifying space (part two)

Tags: commutative-algebra, topological-k-theory, limits-colimits, formal-completions

Continuing [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1728324/how-to-compare-the-k-theory-and-singular-cohomology-of-a-classifying-space), given a compact, connected Lie group $G$, there is a sequence of maps
$$R(G) \to \hat{R}(G) \overset\sim\to K^*(BG) \to \hat{H}^*(BG;\mathbb Q)$$
apparently first discussed by Atiyah and Hirzebruch.
The induced map $K^*(BG) \otimes \mathbb Q \to \hat{H}^*(BG;\mathbb Q)$ isn't an isomorphism; the basic point is that $\mathbb Q[[u]]$ is much bigger than $\mathbb Z[[u]] \otimes \mathbb Q$.

The obvious next question is what happens if one replaces $R(G)$ by $R(G) \otimes \mathbb Q$ at the beginning. I suspect (but am not sure) that things "work" then. To wit, approximate $EG \to BG$ by a sequence $E_n G \to B_n G$ of compact $n$-universal principal $G$-bundles (i.e., such that $\pi_{\leq n}(E_n G) = 0$). The sequence
$$R(G) \otimes \mathbb Q \to K^*(B_n G) \otimes \mathbb Q \overset\sim\longrightarrow H^*(B_n G;\mathbb Q)$$
then should induce in the limit isomorphisms 
$$(R(G) \otimes\mathbb Q)^\wedge
\overset\sim\longrightarrow 
\varprojlim \big(K^*(B_n G) \otimes \mathbb Q\big) \overset\sim\longrightarrow 
\hat{H}^*(BG;\mathbb Q).$$

**1. Is this right?**

If that is correct, there's something else going on I don't understand. Because $\hat R(T)$ is a integral domain and torsion-free over $\mathbb Z$, the same holds of the Weyl invariants $\hat R(T)^W \cong \hat R(G)$. This should mean the obvious map to $\big(R(G) \otimes \mathbb Q\big)^\wedge \cong \hat H^*(BG;\mathbb Q)$ is an injection. This is all very well and satisfying if $\pi_1(G)$ is torsion-free, for then it is known that $R(G)$ is a polynomial ring on $\mathrm{rank}(G)$ generators and so is $H^*(BG;\mathbb Q)$. But this does not hold in general; for example, it is known that 
$$R\big(\mathrm{PSU}(3)\big) \cong \mathbb Z[X,Y,Z]/(Z^3-XY)$$
although $\mathrm{PSU}(3)$ has rank $2$, and 
$$H^*\big(B\mathrm{PSU}(3);\mathbb Q\big) \cong \mathbb Q[c_2,c_3], \qquad |c_j| = 2j.$$
So if the claim in my first question is right, the completion process makes one generator and one relation redundant.

**2. In this example, what does the completion process do?**

I should specify that although I found the description of $R\big(\mathrm{PSU}(3)\big)$ in the paper of Brylinski and Zhang, I'm not clear what relation these generators $X,Y,Z$ have to the fundamental representations and so in particular still don't know what the augmentation ideal is. Is there some place these computations are carried out so I could see what's happening?

Comment: Presumably the point is that $R(PSU(3))$ is not a polynomial ring but it becomes one after completing at the augmentation ideal. That happens sometimes.

Comment: Or power series ring, but that's what I imagine happens. You think the first part is right then?